# Missing rafter baffles

Tags: roof, ventilation

My side attic gets super hot in summer and the room next to it is about six degrees warmer than other rooms. I see rafter baffles/ vents missing where the wall separating the room and the attic meets the roof. The roof slopes up from the wall. IR thermometer readings indicate that the hot air is accumulating at the marked location. There is a vent about 6 feet up the roof from this wall. There is no access to the roof from the other side. What are my options to improve ventilation? Thank you!!

[image: picture]

Comment: I can't tell what I'm looking at here. Am I inside or outside? Are those 2x6 or 2x8 rafters? Do you have soffit ventilation? (It's all moot if not.)